# Linking to Google Cloud Storage files with automatic authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using a Google Cloud Storage bucket to host private files (html, pdfs etc) that are statically linked to from a different service (our ERM) that I have no control over. Therefore, no tokens etc are possible.

Users with access to the bucket can click on the link (eg. `https://storage.cloud.google.com/info_bucket/docs/README.pdf`) but there are issues because the users aren't logged into Google with this account being their primary account so `authuser=x` needs to be appended to the URL sometimes, otherwise there's a Forbidden 403 error.

I have searched high and low and setup a CDN and load balancer to try and have it give the OAuth select account or intelligently select the correct user (they are all in the same business group, same with the bucket). I have a website hosted externally and I have set an A record for a subdomain to the CDN however it still doesn't work as expected. I feel like it should be simpler than what I'm experiencing.

Edit: to explicitly mention that tokens aren't an option.

Comment: You mean that the users get a 403 because their active Google account isn't authorized on the Bucket? They have to switch account before clicking to not have a 403?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere there is no option to switch account. They have to know which user index is equal to the one that has permission. Personally, my authorised account is authuser=2 but for others it's authuser=1. There is no option to switch accounts, when I you click on the link with no authuser parameter, it's a 403 error.

Comment: Hmm, it's a browser issue when you have several accounts logged in the same time. Except to create dedicated context to each account in your browser (I know how to do this with Chrome), I don't see any simple solution for that.

Comment: When I try to log into GMail, or access a new Google/Google authenticated thing, it goes through the OAuth portal. That is the kind of thing I was imagining - ideally without needing to implement a front-end app

Comment: Yes but you have a GMAIL front end that ask you to choose your identity. In the case of Cloud Storage, there isn't front end, only the service that serve the blob.

Comment: I completely agree with @HumptyDumps that this is a major inconvenience. 90% of the time you'd be given a company account and cannot use your personal. And you want to use that one for GCP only, and your personal for everything else. So we should at least be able to set the default account for GCP only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use:

[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

> A signed URL is a URL that provides limited permission and time to
> make a request. Signed URLs contain authentication information in
> their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform
> specific actions on a resource
>
> In some scenarios, you might not want to require your users to have a
> Google account in order to access Cloud Storage, but you still want to
> control access using your application-specific logic. The typical way
> to address this use case is to provide a signed URL to a user, which
> gives the user read, write, or delete access to that resource for a
> limited time.

[Creating a signed URL to download an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#gsutil)

Comment: In my question, I said that the links are statically served from a 3rd party service (our ERM) with no option to add a short-lived token in the user. I need to have a static URL that handles all the authentication. For security, it's not an option to have resources available with infinitely lived tokens.

Comment: I do not think you can implement this solution with a static link that will handle all the authentication.